# Как записать в строку число double, но с двумя знаками после запятой?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Пусть число x=0.9503435034. Я перевожу double в стороку String^ так:

```
str=Convert::ToString(x); т.е str="0.9503435034";
```

А как сделать так, чтобы записать число с двумя знаками после запятой? Например, число x=0.9503435034, а в строку чтобы пошло str="0.95";

Знаю, есть перегруженная функция ToString() класса Convert, выглядит так `Convert::ToString(double value,IFormatProvider provider)`, но я не знаю, что подавать в качестве второго параметра, подскажите, пожалуйста, что, либо другой способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [настраиваемые числовые форматы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx). Чтобы задать ровно **два** знака после точки, подходит шаблон: "0.00":

```
String^ str = String::Format("{0:0.00}", x);
```

P.S. Просто как комментарий: если вы программируете под .NET, работайте с C# - проще будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! А под .NET на С++ я пишу потому, что курсовую написал на С++, класс модели нейронной сети, и работал с ним в консоле, а теперь потребовался к нему графический интефейс, вот и пришлось разбираться в visual studio, честно говоря довольно сложно, но другого выхода не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

```
double x;
char   str[20];
int l = sprintf (str,"%.2f",x);
```

Обратите внимание **sprintf()** возвращает количество записанных символов, это может пригодиться при комплексном форматировании строки для смещения указателя записи в строку.

Comment: `//
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
double x;
string str;
stringstream s;
s << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << x;
str = s.str();
//` вроде так